# how to get a jquery widget to render text rather than an icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Apologies in advance for what is going to be a vague question.

I'm currently hooking up a [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to a site that I'm working on and have, for the most part, successfully styled it as I'd like using CSS.

The widget, however, uses prepackaged icons for the `Previous` and `Next` buttons to move between months (see link above).

I would like to replace these icons with carats instead.

Given that the CSS attached to the jQuery UI library is styling and placing the icons:

```
/* states and images */
.ui-icon {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
.ui-icon,
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png);
}
.ui-widget-header .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png);
}
.ui-state-default .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_ef8c08_256x240.png);
}
.ui-state-hover .ui-icon,
.ui-state-focus .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_ef8c08_256x240.png);
}
.ui-state-active .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_ef8c08_256x240.png);
}
.ui-state-highlight .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_228ef1_256x240.png);
}
.ui-state-error .ui-icon,
.ui-state-error-text .ui-icon {
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_ffd27a_256x240.png);
}
```

is there an easy way to use CSS to place plaintext carats in place of the `background-image`s that have been set up in the CSS?

Comment: what is `carats` and why?

Comment: oh just `<` for back and `>` for next

Comment: why don't try bootstrap [datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

Comment: because I have this one hooked up and almost running the way I want it to :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply remove the icons following after the classes **.ui-datepicker-next and .ui-datepicker-prev** by disabling the **background-image** and then use pseudoselector :*after* to place a character with **content:"your text here"**.

I demonstrated this for you with this **[jsfiddle with date picker (click on the input field)](http://jsfiddle.net/7keSp/)**

[image]

The Css-Code:

```
.ui-datepicker-next .ui-icon-circle-triangle-e, .ui-datepicker-prev .ui-icon-circle-triangle-w {
    background-image: none;
    content:"k";
 position:absolute;
}
.ui-datepicker-next, .ui-datepicker-prev {
      position:relative;  
}

.ui-datepicker-next:after {
    z-index:10000;
    color:black;
    position:absolute;
    left:9px;
    top:4px;
    content: ">";
}
.ui-datepicker-prev:after {
    z-index:10000;
    color:black;
    position:absolute;
    left:9px;
    top:4px;
    content: "<";
}
```

Comment: Your're wellcome fox! I'm glad to helped you.